# Spring boot calling RedisTemplate.execute lua script not concatenating strings

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, lua

I have a spring boot application and am using redis.

I'm excuting this lua script via the redisTemplate:

```
local rootKey = tostring(ARGV[1])
local zSetName = tostring(ARGV[2])
local bothStrings = rootKey .. zSetName
return bothStrings
```

with this in command:

```
redisTemplate.execute(script, Collections.singletonList("1"),"pointRouteCache", "point");
```

Only the first value is returned, ie "pointRouteCache".

I expect to see 'pointRouteCachepoint' but I only get 'pointRouteCache', why is that the case?

I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.4.RELEASE